# Multiline underset in amsmath and related packages

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I have created a command `\myunder` that places colored sans-serif text under a mathematical expression, using the `underset` command found in `amsmath` and related packages. Text color is achieved with the `xcolor` package.

I would like to modify `\myunder` so that I can place a second line of colored text under the math expressions.

Here is a MWE. Unfortunately, as you can see in the second equation, using `\\` doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\myunder}[3][]{%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{\underset{\textsf{#3}}{#2}}{\underset{\textsf{\textcolor{#1}{#3}}}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\mylongsymbol}{\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Gamma_{\alpha}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \myunder[red]{\mylongsymbol}{System X} < \myunder[blue]{\mylongsymbol}{System Y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \myunder[red]{\mylongsymbol}{System X\\X is real.} < \myunder[blue]{\mylongsymbol}{System Y\\Y is imaginary.}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myunder}{omm}
 {% #1 = color, #2 = main symbol, #3 = the underscript
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {% no optional argument
    \andrew_myunder:nnn { } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {% optional argument should be a color name
    \andrew_myunder:nnn { \color{#1} } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__andrew_myunder_sub_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andrew_myunder:nnn
 {
  \__andrew_myunder_split:n { #3 }
  \underset
   {% the underscript in \underset
    #1 % the possible color
    \substack
     {% add \\ between the items
      \seq_use:Nn \l__andrew_myunder_sub_seq { \\ }
     }
   }
   {% the main symbol in \underset
    #2
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__andrew_myunder_split:n
 {% split the input at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__andrew_myunder_sub_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % add \textsf{} around each item
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__andrew_myunder_sub_seq \l__andrew_myunder_sub_seq { \textsf{##1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mylongsymbol}{\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Gamma_{\alpha}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \myunder[red]{\mylongsymbol}{System X} < \myunder[blue]{\mylongsymbol}{System Y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \myunder[red]{\mylongsymbol}{System X\\X is real.} < 
  \myunder[blue]{\mylongsymbol}{System Y\\Y is imaginary.}
\end{equation}

\huge

\begin{equation}
  \myunder[red]{\mylongsymbol}{System X\\X is real.} < 
  \myunder[blue]{\mylongsymbol}{System Y\\Y is imaginary.}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

First we normalize the arguments: if no optional argument is given, the main function is called with an empty first argument, so no color is set.

The first mandatory argument is just used as is for the second argument to `\underset`. The second mandatory argument is first split at `\\` tokens; the items so obtained are then transformed into `\textsf{<item>}`. Finally the sequence is used reinserting `\\` between items, all fed to `\substack`.

Note that no explicit `\scriptsize` instruction is issued, so `\underset` does its normal job of selecting the appropriate font size.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you'll most likely only use this within a display math environment, the following is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\myunder}[3][black]{
  \underset{\mbox{\scriptsize\color{#1}\sffamily\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#3\end{tabular}}}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\mylongsymbol}{\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Gamma_{\alpha}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \myunder[red]{\mylongsymbol}{System X} < \myunder[blue]{\mylongsymbol}{System Y}
\]

\[
  \myunder[red]{\mylongsymbol}{System X \\ X is real.} < \myunder[blue]{\mylongsymbol}{System Y \\ Y is imaginary.}
\]

\end{document}
```

There's no real need for conditioning on the existence of an optional argument since you can print content in `black` if needed.